# Laravel - Method Not Allowed HTTP Exception (RouteCollection.php line 218)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I'm currently new on Laravel and trying to develop my first project. I have this `MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218` error during my development for inserting data into database. I have searched both Google & Stackoverflow for solutions but non are related to my current problem and some of them way too complex for this simple problem (I think so...).

I have my form in my checklist page:-

```
<form action="{{url('addchecklist')}}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <div class="text-left">
                        <input type="hidden" name="schmFK" value="{{$id}}">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <h4>
                                <label>Section</label>
                                <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true" name="sctionPK">
                                    <option selected>Select the Section</option>
                                    @foreach ($sction as $key=>$slct1)
                                    <option value="{{$slct1->ssctionPK}}">{{strtoupper($slct1->ssctionName)}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-2">
                        <button type="button" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="margin-top:33px; padding-top:7px; padding-bottom:7px;">Add Section</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <h4>
                                <label>Severity</label>
                                <select class="selectpicker form-control" name="svrityPK">
                                    <option selected>Select the Severity</option>
                                    @foreach ($svrity as $key=>$slct2)
                                    <option value="{{$slct2->severityPK}}">{{strtoupper($slct2->severityName)}}</option>
                                    @endforeach
                                </select>
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <h4>
                                <label>Question</label>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Question" name="question">
                            </h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            @include('widgets.button', array('class'=>'primary btnaddstd', 'size'=>'lg', 'type'=>'submit', 'value'=>'Add Checklist'))
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
```

Then I have this route for inserting data from the form into database:-

```
Route::post('/addchecklist', function (Request $request){

    // Create instance to store record
    $scheme = new App\checklists;
    $scheme->schmFK = $request->schmFK;
    $scheme->schSectionFK = $request->sctionPK;
    $scheme->severityFK = $request->svrityPK;
    $scheme->clQuestion = $request->question;
    $scheme->save(); // save the input


    // Sort all records descending to retrieve the newest added record
    $input = App\checklists::orderBy('cklistPK','desc')->first();

    // Set search field variable default value of null
    $src = isset($src) ? $src : null;

    // Get Checklist reference from cklists_stddetails with the designated ID
    $chkstd = App\Cklists_stddetail::where('cklistFK', $input->cklistPK)
                                ->join('stddetails', 'stdDtlFK', '=', 'stddetails.sdtlPK')
                                ->get();

    // Get the newest stored record
    $chcklst = App\checklists::where('cklistPK', $input->cklistPK)->firstOrFail();

    // Get all data from table 'stddetails'
    $stddetail = App\stddetails::all();

    // Get all data from table 'standards'
    $stndrd = App\standard::all();

    // Get all data from table 'sections'
    $sction = App\Section::all();


    // Redirect to 'addref.blade' page with the newest added record
    return redirect('addref/'.$input->cklistPK)
        ->with('src', $src)
        ->with('chkstd', $chkstd)
        ->with('id',$input->cklistPK)
        ->with('schmid', $request->schmFK)
        ->with('chcklst', $chcklst)
        ->with('stddetail', $stddetail)
        ->with('stndrd', $stndrd)
        ->with('sction', $sction);
});
```

My scenario is this, I have a form for user to input data in it. Then when the data is saved, they will be redirected to the page of that data to do something there. **The data is successfully saved** in the database but the redirection to the designated page (addref.blade) with the newest record ID return error:-

[image: MethodNotAllowedHttpException Error]

But the URL goes where I wanted it to go (means the **URL is right**):-

[image: Success URL]

As you can see, the usual solution from the net that I found are:-

*Make sure both method from routes and the form is the same*, and mine it is:-

```
method="POST"

Route::post
```

*Make sure the URL routes can recognize the form's action URL*, and mine it is:-

```
<form action="{{url('addchecklist')}}" method="POST">

Route::post('/addchecklist', function (Request $request)
```

*Include CSRF token field in the form*, and mine it have been included:-

```
<form action="{{url('addchecklist')}}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
```

I have tried those simple solution provided on the net and nothing is helpful enough. I'm still wondering what else I have missed and hoped that anyone here can assist on solving my issue.

Comment: php artisan route:clear and then try

Comment: @JYoThI Same thing happen..

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that you have a redirect which you have not registered in your `routes or web.php` file.

Sample redirect:

```
Route::post('/addchecklist', function (Request $request){
    //some post process here...

    return redirect('addref/'.$input->cklistPK)
        ->with('src', $src)
        ->with('chkstd', $chkstd)
        ->with('id',$input->cklistPK)
        ->with('schmid', $request->schmFK)
        ->with('chcklst', $chcklst)
        ->with('stddetail', $stddetail)
        ->with('stndrd', $stndrd)
        ->with('sction', $sction);
});

Route::get('addref/{id}', function(Request $request){
     //show the blade.php with data
});
```

Comment: What do you mean? I have the redirect in the routes that situated in my `web.php` and there's the proof, you have copied it in your sample.

Comment: before you call any redirect inside, you need to check first that the route name you want to redirect is registered in your web.php else laravel can't find that. So for that example, you need to have two routes. one is for post method and the other one is for the redirect.

Comment: So what you're saying is that I have to create a route that redirect to another route which that second route redirect to the view? Like this:  `Route 1 (Save data) -> Route 2 (Get data & redirect) -> View Page (Redirected page)`?

Comment: @Kaydarin, yes or you can also have a controller to handle the saving process and to make your routes more cleaner.

Comment: Never tried that route to route technique before, might as well try it. About controllers, well my bad... I just don't want to open lots of pages. Btw, from your sample, `Route::get('addref/{id}', function(Request $request)`, it should be `Route::get('addref/{id}', function($id)` right? Because I'm not sure that the second route can read that `Request`.

Comment: Thank you, this going to take time to get used to it. My code is now getting more complex. I'll try my best to use your method....

Answer (score -1):

Can you please write :

url('/addchecklist')

instead of :

url('addchecklist')

and then print_r('in');
and die; and check what you get.

```
  Route::post('/addchecklist', function (Request $request){

      print_r('in');
      die;
  });
```

Comment: ok then your URL route working perfectly lol. there is no error with route.